# Rad Ajax Loading Panel not showing up on postback in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik

I have been at this for a couple of hours now. I have a Aspx page, with a couple user controls. Whenever I call any javascipt on the user control the listview updates but does not show the dialog. Can anyone please tell me why or any information. Here is my code.
aspx page

User control javascript

```
 var album = $(this).prev().val();
                    $('[id$=AccessChoice]').val(option);
                    $find("<%= RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(Page).ClientID %>").ajaxRequest(album);
```

User control

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy  ID="FullAlbumAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="FullAlbumAjaxManager1">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ListViewPanel1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="lvFullControlAlbums" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="FullAlbumCounter" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="ListViewPanel1">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ListViewPanel1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="lvFullControlAlbums" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="FullAlbumCounter" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="lvFullControlAlbums">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ListViewPanel1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="lvFullControlAlbums" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="FullAlbumCounter" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rdoSortDate">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ListViewPanel1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="lvFullControlAlbums" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rdoSortName">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ListViewPanel1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="lvFullControlAlbums" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy >
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" MinDisplayTime="0" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an old question, but I'll try to answer as I've got this same problem, and this is my solution:

`ListView` doesn't renders to an HTML tag (I assume `ListViewPanel1` and `lvFullControlAlbums` are ListViews), so you should wrap these controls in a `Panel` and modify the `AjaxSettings` accordingly:

```
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="FullAlbumAjaxManager1">
    <UpdatedControls>
        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ListViewWrapper" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
    </UpdatedControls>
</telerik:AjaxSetting>

<asp:Panel ID="ListViewWrapper" runat="server">
    <asp:ListView ID="ListViewPanel1" runat="server" >
        <!-- your code here -->
    </asp:ListView>
</asp:Panel>
```

Probably `FullAlbumCounter` is also a control which itself is not rendered as an HTML tag only its content. In this case you should do the same.

See:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/listview/loading-panel-not-showing-up.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! (Also applies to Repeater or any other control that doesn't render to HTML)

Answer (score 0):

Should have had AjaxManager1 instead of FullAlbumAjaxManager1 in one of the ajax settings